# How to deal with environment variables and concurrency in Django

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

I'm working on a web application (using Django) that use another software to make some processing. This software needs to set its working directory to be in the environment variables. When a client make a request the app create the working directory (create data to be used by the external software). Then set the environment variable used by the external software to the created directory. Finally we call the external software and get the result.

Here's a summary of what the app is doing :

```
def request(data):
    path = create_working_directory(data)
    os.environ['WORKING_DIRECTORY'] = path
    result = call_the_external_software()
```

I haven't tested this yet (in reality it's not as simple as in this example). I'm thinking to execute this function in new process. Will I have problems when multiple client make simultaneous requests? If yes what should I do to fix the problems?

ps : I can't change anything on the external program.

Comment: Does the request have to return the result of the external software? If not, one option is to use a message queue in which you can guarantee that only one message is processed at once.

Comment: Also, how are you calling the external software? If you're using subprocess, you can set environment variables as part of the invocation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: @Joe Yes the application should return the result of the external software after processing it.

Comment: I call the software using with functions that provided by a python library. The software is not written on Python.

Comment: Then you need to ensure your server is single-threaded or you'll have problems. Possibly put it behind a reverse-proxy like nginx to ensure that only that path has a single concurrent connection?

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen. Note that Popen takes a "env" argument that you can use to define environment variables in the child call.

```
def request(data):
    path = create_working_directory(data)
    env = {"WORKING_DIRECTORY": path}
    result = subprocess.call([ext_script] + ext_args, env=env)
    return result # presumably
```

Comment: As user230137 said, the external program isn't called with `subprocess` but with Python functions.